# Hosting an existing Angular website

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sass, web, web-hosting

I am working on a website for a family friend. It's a fairly simple Angular SPA with 3 'pages'. When I'm done, I plan to bundle it into an html, css, and js file. In addition, I own the domain that I'd like to use through google domains.

Currently, I am trying to find a hosting service that will let me upload my 3 files (html, js, & css) and just host it. However, I haven't found any services that let me do that other than AWS. So far, I've tried weebly and squarespace and they make me use their templates and GUI to build the website. If I needed, I could just use their templates. However, I'd prefer to bbuild it from scratch so I can practice my Angular and Node Skills.

Any suggestions for website hosting services that let me upload the html, css, and js files of a website I've already built?

Thank you.

Comment: [ballonbit](https://www.bitballoon.com/)

Comment: I am using AWS S3 for this exact use-case.  It works great and is super-cheap.

Comment: sorry?? .. i think every serve and histing let you upload files :-)

Comment: S3 can only host static content, which if fine if that's all you need. Otherwise  you want to use EC2, or just use a free dyno on Heroku.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. You have to provide something you've tried and errors or the unexpected you're getting. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with any website that supports FTP. If you are looking for something really simple, see:
https://www.bluehost.com/

Amazon, recently launched a service just for this purpose. See:
https://amazonlightsail.com/

Answer (score 0):

Best place to do it : https://pages.github.com/ 
You can link your domain to gihtub's IP.

If you feel gh-pages are tought. Try others like https://www.hostinger.in/, https://www.hostinger.com/ , https://in.000webhost.com/